# Mac Version of JS Fiddle

Tags: osx, javascript, web-development, css, html-editor

I really like using JSFiddle for testing code, but unfortunately, it isn't very good when it comes to testing code with AJAX requests due to various security features to prevent cross-site scripting, ect. Is there a desktop version for MacOsX?

Necessary features:

- Just start coding. Unlike an IDE, no need to create a bunch of separate files, add in boilerplate, add links to Javascript and CSS files.
- Separate windows for HTML, CSS, Javascript and preview.
- Ability to run code
- Allows AJAX requests to different domains without running into security issues.

Bonus features:

- Syntax highlighting
- Tidy/autoformat code
- Saves files to the cloud

Comment: Let's hope you get across-platform solution :-)